# C to Fortran: Interoperability of a C pointer to a char array, declared in a struct

Tags: c, fortran, interop

I am creating Fortran bindings to a C library. The C header defines a `struct` as follows:

```
struct frame {
  char *foo[4];
  int  bar;
};
```

(in reality, the C struct is much more complicated, I just stripped it down to the essential part). Now, the C library also provides a function that gives values to the struct. For the purposes of this question, I wrote a simplified replacement of such a function:

```
void setFrame(struct frame *fr) {
  fr->bar=12;
  printf("bar in C: %d\n", fr->bar);
}
```

(I don't really care about the value of `foo`, but I do care about the value of `bar`, and I won't get it correctly on the Fortran side if `foo` isn't declared properly). Now, this is my Fortran implementation of the above:

```
module binding
use iso_c_binding
implicit none
private

type, bind(c), public :: frame
  integer(kind=c_int), dimension(4) :: foo
  integer(kind=c_int) :: bar
end type Frame

public :: setFrame

interface
  subroutine setFrame_C(fr) bind(c, name="setFrame")
  import :: c_ptr
  type(c_ptr), value :: fr
  end subroutine setFrame_C
end interface

contains

subroutine setFrame(fr)
type(frame), intent(inout), target :: fr
call setFrame_C(c_loc(fr))
end subroutine setFrame

end module binding
```

and this is a test Fortran program:

```
program test
use binding
implicit none
type(frame) :: fr
print "(a,i0)","bar in Fortran (before calling setFrame): ",fr%bar
call setFrame(fr)
print "(a,i0)","bar in Fortran (after calling setFrame): ",fr%bar
end program test
```

Running the above program gives:

```
bar in Fortran (before calling setFrame): -1076110840
bar in C: 12
bar in Fortran (after calling setFrame): 12
```

meaning the Fortran binding works. Note that the equivalent of `char *foo[4]` is an integer array of `c_int`. This is a bit surprising because, although there is not much of a difference between a C integer and a C char, I would expect C char to be a one-byte integer. Now, if I declare `char *foo[4]` in a more "natural" way:

```
character(kind=c_char), dimension(4) :: foo
```

it doesn't work (I don't get the correct value for `fr.bar`). The reason is that, at least in gfortran 11.2.0, `c_int` is actually equal to 4 while `c_char` is equal to 1. Even `character(kind=c_int)` works. I fact, `character(kind=4)` also works, although the compiler (correctly) issues a warning in this case.

So my question is... what is actually the correct, "formal" way to treat `char *foo[4]` on the Fortran side, portable to another compiler that probably treats C char in another way?

Comment: An `integer` is interoperable only with a `signed char` or an `unsigned char` instead of a `char` (and then `integer(c_signed_char)` which may be different from `integer(c_int)`.)

Comment: @francescalus: At least in gfortran, `c_signed_char` is equal to 1, and it is indeed different than `c_int` (which is 4). So`integer(c_signed_char)` won't work because `integer(c_int)` works. There is no `unsigned char` in iso_c_binding, so the only option is `integer(c_int)`, but I am not sure this is portable.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `char *foo[4];` is an array of four pointers to char, so your interoperable declaration in Fortran has to be

```
type, bind(c), public :: frame
  type(c_ptr), dimension(4) :: foo
  integer(kind=c_int) :: bar
end type Frame
```

Your way only happens to work because you are probably testing on a 32bit platform where a pointer has the same width as an int.

Comment: That's what I wanted to avoid. It is obviously portable, but the developer of the C library sometimes uses something like `fr->foo[i]="a"` to assign values, and `*fr->foo[i]` to get values from `foo`. I wanted to have the same functionality on the Fortran side, with a similar syntax. Defining `foo` as an array of `c_ptr` requires special procedures like `setFoo` and `getFoo` to do this (which works perfectly fine, but I wanted the Fortran code to look as much as its C counterpart for immediate comparisons). It seems this is not possible in this case.

Comment: Just a remark though, it's best to initialize `foo` in the declaration, as `type(c_ptr), dimension(3) :: foo=c_null_ptr` to avoid segmentation faults in case the user of the API tries to get the value of `fr%foo` in a function (say, `getFoo(fr)`), while `foo` wasn't initialized yet.

Comment: @Pap In my experience, it's better to use valgrind which catches uses of unitialized memory to avoid such problems. That's because the function that a Fortran compiler generates to initialize variables of derived types that have default initialization can have some unexpected side effects (like long compilations or bugs on entry to functions containing such variables).

Comment: And yes, duplicating the C pointer assignment directly with similar syntax is not possible in Fortran. If you want to stick to integers, you can try to use `INTEGER(c_intptr_t)` which isn't guaranteed to occupy the same amount of storage as a `TYPE(c_ptr)` but on all platforms I have access to, it does.

Comment: `integer(kind=c_intptr_t)` does work, indeed. Nevertheless I decided to stay on the safe side and go on with this project. In the end, this is going to be extended to a full object-oriented version, where each derived type will have private variables anyway, and its own public methods to get or set them.
I always use valgrind to detect any leaks. This is more or less imperative when dealing with C code. In this particular case though, the C developer wrote a pretty clean code. Valgrind reports zero errors in the Fortran code using the C library. Thank you for all the information provided.